# How to add event listener for Threejs Mesh Object using threex dom events?

Tags: javascript, three.js, dom-events, onclicklistener

```
var domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, view.domElement);

var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    div.setAttribute('data-remove','mesh1');
    div.className = 'close-me';

var label = new THREE.CSS2DObject( div );
    label.position.set( -(w / 2.1) , 0 , 0.1 );
    mesh1.add( label );

    domEvents.addEventListener(div, 'click', find, true);
    function find(event){
        alert('hey its me');
    }
```

Here i am using threex to add click event on mesh object but i am getting some console error like:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: THREEx is not defined
2. threex.domevents.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
3. Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

I am using threex cdn which is given below:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/threex-domevents@1.0.0/threex.domevents.min.js"></script>
```

kindly help me and any help would be very appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.
For some reason I couldn't get it to work using the CDN. Try using the file from their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents). Copy the file "threex.domevents.js" to your project directory and then import it in your html:

```
<script src="threex.domevents.js"></script>
```

It worked for me.