# Importing threex.domevents.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 0.2, 2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var domEvents   = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement)

camera.position.z = 5;
camera.position.y = 1;
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

body {
    color: rgb(47, 47, 202);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Orbit</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/7/Stats.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/16.6.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/threex-domevents@1.0.0/threex.domevents.js"></script>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I have hard time finding out how to import threex.domevents. Console gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at threex.domevents.js:67:1" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: THREEx is not defined at main.js:1:17"

I don't want to use node.js, because I think Django is better.

Comment: https://unpkg.com/threex-domevents@1.0.0/threex.domevents.js is not returning the script

Comment: When I go to sources I find this underlined "module.exports = function initializeDomEvents(THREE, THREEx) {". I tried downloading it, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: That link is broken.  Try https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/threex.domevents@1.0.1/threex.domevents.js instead

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956648/1544886

Comment: Thank you very much! How did I not find that :D